# execute function in procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

can I execute function within procedure in mysql

surf a lot but didnt find relevant stuff.
seen several error solution but did'nt get any proper method where function can be execute within procedure in mysql.
so want help me with it

Comment: Have you tried it first to see what happens?

Comment: Function cannot be "executed", it must be used in some expression. If your function performs some action then you may SET its output to some unused user-defined variable.